# Chrome extension - create window - focused property not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I create a window with function

```
chrome.windows.create({
    focused: false
})
```

but the new window is always focused and go on top so is it a bug or I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug of Chrome, or if it is OS-related, but I had trouble with this kne before. I always end up calling `chrome.windows.update(...)` (in `create(...)`'s callback) and make the desired window focused.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again with Today's canary build?  The build may have been in a broken state for a few days with a recent checkin, but the developer told me it should be working now.

Comment: Yes. This is a very new feature. In v33 the behavior won't be quite right on Windows and won't work at all on ChromeOS. In v34 it should work properly. If you are still having problems file a bug at crbug.com and include version and OS information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this as the callback of creating window? But it seems that the new created window will still show and hide soon with this method.

```
function createWinSucceed(window) {
  var id = window.id;
  chrome.windows.update(id, { focused: false });
};
```

Comment: sorry but pls see next my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank LarryLee, I tried as you suggest but it doesn't work

```
chrome.windows.create({
        focused: false
    }, function(window){
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, { focused: false })
})
```

still I changed to

```
chrome.windows.create({
        focused: **true**
    }, function(window){
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, { focused: false })
})
```

It works but it makes a flash when window creating and lose focus. Sometime it takes my focus on current working window and makes the computer slowly. I think it's not a good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It still is a problem on Windows. It is not a problem on my Mac.

On Windows, the work-around of superpan3000 himself works for me, for which I'm grateful!

I'm referring to the solution

```
function createWinSucceed(window) {
  var id = window.id;
  chrome.windows.update(id, { focused: false });
};
```

BTW When re-using the created window, no more flashing will occur.